# Organization of Files on Top of Remix Screen

Tags: solidity

Is there a way to click and drag the files from the top of the screen on remix to better organize my coding?

Comment: What do you mean by "top of the screen"? If you mean the open files tabs, it seems that is not possible. It seems a nice thing to have, try suggesting it as a feature in remix github project.